# Is there any file attribute indicating that a particular file has been synced with cloud

Tags: data-synchronization, cloud-storage

how to determine that a file is synced with cloud. Does the file contain any unique attribute to find this? If so what kind of information can be obtained (say file synced time, added or modified time) from that attribute?

Comment: that really depends on the syncing mechanism. Dropbox, or Google Drive, or..?

Comment: for both google drive and dropbox

Comment: for all kinds of cloud services in general

Comment: certainly the answer for "every single cloud service ever" must be no.

Comment: also, the answer to dropbox seems to be no: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Need-for-DOS-command-to-know-if-files-are-already-synched/td-p/201505